# AttributeError: type object 'projectile' has no attribute 'dir'

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, pygame

Hey guys I'm sorry bothering you, but I wasted hours now tinkering around in order to get this to work.

Code worked fine, but the projectiles kept changing direction after they were fired, so I tried to assign every Bullet its own dir value and put the shot function which moves the bullets into the projectile class. But I keep getting the error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "PycharmProjects/Game/Pygame.py", line 90, in  update() File "PycharmProjects/Game/Pygame.py", line 73, in update get_input() File "PycharmProjects/Game/Pygame.py", line 55, in get_input projectile.dir == {'N'} AttributeError: type object 'projectile' has no attribute 'dir'

I think it's pretty obvious that I'm new to coding so I'd be pretty thankful for some help.

Changing projectile.dir in get_input function to bullet.dir and just dir.
Put the direction in brackets. Assigned direction outside of get_input function. Assigned the letter in class projectile before init function

```py
class player():
    x = WIDTH / 2
    y = HEIGHT / 2
    width = 50
    height = 50
    speed = 1

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 255), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

class projectile():

    radius = 10
    speed = 8

    def __init__(self, x, y, dir={}):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.dir = dir

    def shot(self):
        for bullet in bullets:
            if self.dir == 'N':
                print('N')
                self.y -= 1
            if self.dir == 'W':
                print('W')
                self.x -= 1
            if self.dir == 'S':
                print('S')
                self.y += 1
            if self.dir == 'E':
                print('E')
                self.x += 1

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, (255, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y), self.radius)


def get_input():
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    ev = pygame.event.get()

    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        player.y -= player.speed
        projectile.dir == 'N'
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        player.x -= player.speed
        projectile.dir == 'W'
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        player.y += player.speed
        projectile.dir == 'S'
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        player.x += player.speed
        projectile.dir == 'E'
    for event in ev:
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            bullets.append(projectile(round(player.x + player.width//2), round(player.y + player.height//2), dir))


def update():
    clock.tick(300)
    win.fill ((0, 0, 0))
    get_input()
    player.draw()
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw()
        bullet.shot()
    pygame.display.update()


running = True
player = player()
bullets = []

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    update()

#pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Here is the error message:Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PycharmProjects/Game/Pygame.py", line 90, in <module> update()
File "PycharmProjects/Game/Pygame.py", line 73, in update get_input()
File "PycharmProjects/Game/Pygame.py", line 55, in get_input 
projectile.dir == {'N'}
AttributeError: type object 'projectile' has no attribute 'dir'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.dir` now is an [instance attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects), so the class attribute `projectile.dir` doesnt exist any more.
Create a variable `current_dir` in global name space. Use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt) to write to the variable in the function `get_input` and use the variable to set the direction when an new `projectile` object is constructed:

```py
current_dir = 'N'
def get_input(ev):
    global current_dir

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        player.y -= player.speed
        current_dir = 'N'
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        player.x -= player.speed
        current_dir = 'W'
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        player.y += player.speed
        current_dir = 'S'
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        player.x += player.speed
        current_dir = 'E'

    for event in ev:
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            px, py = round(player.x + player.width//2), round(player.y + player.height//2)
            new_prj = projectile(px, py, current_dir)
            bullets.append(new_prj)
```

Side note, `==` is the compare equal operator. To set `current_dir` you've to use the assignment operator `=`.

Avoid multiple calls to [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) in the main loop. Get the events once and pass the list of events to the functions `update` and `get_input`:

```py
def update(ev):
    clock.tick(300)
    win.fill ((0, 0, 0))
    get_input(ev)
    player.draw()
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw()
        bullet.shot()
    pygame.display.update()

running = True
player = player()
bullets = []

while running:
    ev = pygame.event.get()
    for event in ev:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    update(ev)
```

Comment: Why? I thought the direction was only set in one of the four key-press checks.

Comment: @Guimoute Yes, but the state is stored and used later when the mouse button is pressed. Note `current_dir` is not "reset", when ever the mouse button is pressed, then the bullet has to fire in the last choose direction. `current_dir` is not allowed to be undefined, in the original code (question) it was a class attribute and persistent, too.

Comment: Thanks really helped a lot especially the tip regarding multiple event calls :)